# Selecting table entries where a given date is between the :start date and :end date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an object that has a start date and an end date, in order to represent the time that the object is valid.
Given a date, is there a way to only select those objects that have valid ranges that contain the date?

I tried fiddling with between, but couldn't get the syntax right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often implemented using a named scope that does the appropriate restriction that identifies which records are visible at the current point in time:

```
class MyRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :visible,
    :conditions => 'visible_from<=UTC_TIMESTAMP() AND visible_to>=UTC_TIMESTAMP'
end
```

This can be altered to use place-holders for more arbitrary dates:

```
class MyRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :visible_at, lambda { |date| {
    :conditions => [
      'visible_from<=? AND visible_to>=?',
      date, date
    ]
  }}
end
```

Presumably your dates are stored as UTC, as it is a considerable nuisance to convert from one local-time to another for the purposes of display.

You can select all visible models like this:

```
@records = MyRecord.visible.all
@records = MyRecord.visible_at(2.weeks.from_now)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were doing this for "given_date".

```
select *
from table
where start_date <= given_date
and end_date >= given_date
```

Comment: By the way, isn't this an SQL question?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you'd do it using active record.

```
Foo.find(:all, :conditions => ['valid_from <= ? and valid_to >= ?', valid_date, valid_date])
```